# how to translate this hpricot code to nokogiri?

Tags: nokogiri, hpricot

```
 Hpricot(html).inner_text.gsub("\r"," ").gsub("\n"," ").split(" ").join(" ")

hpricot = Hpricot(html)
hpricot.search("script").remove
hpricot.search("link").remove
hpricot.search("meta").remove
hpricot.search("style").remove
```

found it on http://www.savedmyday.com/2008/04/25/how-to-extract-text-from-html-using-rubyhpricot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri and Hpricot are pretty interchangeable. I.e. Nokogiri(html) is an equivalent of Hpricot(html). Not really sure I understand what the linked article is trying to achieve, but to:

> Extract text from HTML body which includes ignoring large white spaces between tags and words.

This would be an easier approach in Hpricot, and remove the need for the `hpricot.search("script").remove` bits. I.e. Just get the body in the first place:

```
Hpricot(html).search('body').inner_text.gsub("\r"," ").gsub("\n"," ").split(" ").join(" ")
```

And in Nokogiri:

```
Nokogiri(html).search('body').inner_text.gsub("\r"," ").gsub("\n"," ").split(" ").join(" ")
```